# Are the reach value of insights with breakdowns wrong?

Tags: facebook-marketing-api, facebook-insights

There are my campaign insights data from api which come from the same campaign.

The total reach of the breakdowns data is 2858 (added by 68 + 2790), that is different with non-breakdowns data 2856(the value with manager is the same).

Btw, the others value, e.g., impressions, spend ..., are all correct.

Is there a reason cause the two data count are different?

```
# with breakdowns
[
    {
        ...
        "reach": "68",
        "impression_device": "ipad",
        ....
    },
    {
        ...
        "reach": "2790",
        "impression_device": "iphone",
        ....
    },
]

# without breakdown
[
    {
        ...
        "reach": "2856",
        ....
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine situation:
You have 2790 'unique' people with iphone's.
You have 68 'unique' people with ipad's.

So you see 2790 + 68 = 2858

Grand you will say that should be awesome to wrap them in the same campaign.
Ok so lets do that and then we have 2856 but why not 2858 ??? you will ask:

Where are my 2 additional guys?
Because of two lucky bastards have not only iphone but also ipad, so they are the same person. Thats why! ;)

[image]